# Get Image with Xpath using class of Div

Tags: html, class, xpath

How do I write the xpath to get the main news image [in this article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/08/11/us-usa-campaign-romney-idUSBRE87919120120811?feedType=RSS&feedName=wtMostRead&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20reuters/MostRead%20%28News%20/%20US%20/%20Most%20Read%20Articles%29)?

The below one failed for me.

```
//div[contains(@class,'sectionColumns')]//div[contains(@class,'column2']//*img"]
```

I want it to return all images in case of slideshow. I want it to be flexible as some classes
change when news changes.

Comment: Please post the *relevant* markup in the question. There is no telling if that content will exist even this afternoon. Memorialize your request by including the markup.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at "this article", there is an obvious syntax error in your XPath expression:

```
//div[contains(@class,'sectionColumns')]//div[contains(@class,'column2']//*img"]
```

The substring of the above:`*img"`, contains two errors -- `*` followed by a name,  and  an unbalanced quote.

**Probably you want**:

```
//div[contains(@class,'sectionColumns')]//div[contains(@class,'column2']//img]
```